# Mac OS X / iTunes not recognizing iPod?

Tags: itunes, mac, ipod-shuffle

I've plugged in a iPod into my iMac. I've plugged it to the back of the mac where the USB Ports are. It does charge the iPod but whenever i want to add music or delete music i can't since iTunes / My Mac won't recognize my device.

Can anyone help me out here?

For anyone out there here's what a iPod Shuffle looks like : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a format issue. In non-iOS products, there's something called a format. If you originally synced it to a PC, then it won't sync with a Mac (and vise versa). The only way to sync it with the other computer is to format it. This (hopefully) won't be a problem because of iTunes in the cloud, which syncs your music throughout your computers. I hope this helps!